# What is the easy way to read a NetCDF file and convert/write into CSV file as readable file?

Tags: python, csv, netcdf

can anyone please help me and give me an example of how to read a NetCDF file using Python and convert it into CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Just load your file to `pandas` library and convert it to CSV or even plot your info with the help of `matplotlib.pyplot`.